# check box uncheck issue, its asking two clicks to uncheck the checkbox ,not able to uncheck with single click

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have checkbox inside grid and when i'm selecting checkbox its got selected , but issue when trying to unselected the check box it asks two clicks to uncheck the checkbox.

$('tr .chkbx', "#Grid").on('change', function (e) {

});

Comment: can you show your html code

Comment: <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" id="chId" value="@role.Id" name="@role.Description" /> @role.Description

Comment: that is template which i'm using inside grid column

Comment: Firstly your jquery selector is wrong. Try this...
$('tr .chkbx, #Grid').on('change', function (e) {
   alert(e);
});

Comment: Added that but No use... :(

Comment: There may be some other code interfering it but without seen it its hard to guess. Here is a sample code I created on jsfiddle and it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/dm6wfbpx/